# How to fill in columns of 2D arrays from 1D array

Tags: java

Hi i'm in my first year college computer science and for school we must do a java project (little game) with warriors fighting each others. The point is that they unfortunately "forced" us using specific methods.

So for the "superpower Skills" of each warrior we have a boolean table. We must use a boolean array so that we later can check if a certain warrior has a specific superSkill or not

I thought to write a String method that retrieve the String value of each boolean element and then put that method in column 2 of my 2D - array.

My question is: that at column n°2 of my 2D-Array i would like to put each boolean value from my superSkills array at the right row.

I tried to put at column 2 my method retrieveBoolean but as you can see it gives me all the boolean array at [row1 column2, row2, column2 and row 3 , column2] which i don't want, i want each element e1, e2 of my boolean array to match at row1column1,row2column2...

```
public class SuperSkills {

private static boolean[] superSkills = { true, false, true };

public static String retrieveSkills() {
    String myS = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < superSkills.length; i++) {
        myS += String.valueOf(superSkills[i]);
    }

    return myS;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] myArray = { { "X0", "", "Z1" }, 
            { "X1", "", "Z1" }, 
            { "X2", "", "Z2" } };

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
            myArray[j][1] = retrieveSkills();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));

}
```

I know it has something to do with my concatenation of my myS in my method retrieveSkills but i do not know how to solve that issue.

OUTPUT:

```
[[X0, truefalsetrue, Z1], [X1, truefalsetrue, Z1], [X2, truefalsetrue, Z2]]
```

What i would like to i have:

```
[[X0, true, Z1], [X1, false, Z1], [X2, true, Z2]]
```

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: I fail to understand what you want to achieve. If something is a boolean, don't represent it as a String. Keep it as a boolean. I also have no idea of what the 2D array is for. I'd expect to see a `Warrior` class, containing a field `skills` of type `boolean[]` (since you're apparently forced to represent skills as a boolean array)

Comment: `myArray[j][1] = String.valueOf(superSkills[j]); `will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answers it worked ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] myArray = { { "X0", "", "Z1" }, 
            { "X1", "", "Z1" }, 
            { "X2", "", "Z2" } };

    for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
            myArray[j][1] = String.valueOf(superSkills[j]);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));
}
```

The method retrieveSkills() isn't need, because you want to save only one boolean value from superSkills, "for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)" isn't need, because you never use i and do some operation in every interation of this "for(...".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're generating all the "boolean strings" in a single String variable *myS*, so we're gonna change a bit of code and I'll explain why.
First, at method *superSkills()*, we're gonna make the method to directly return the asked value by making this little changes:

```
 public static String retrieveSkills(int skillID) {
  try {
    return String.valueOf(superSkills[skillID]);
  } catch (Exception e) {
     return "NA";
  }
}
```

By doing this we just need to send the skillID or column to get it as a string, notice that we place it in a try-catch just in case, we do this when we use arrays as a good practice.

Then we just send the skillID to the method in the main

```
myArray[j][1] = String.valueOf(superSkills[j]);
```

Comment: Oh okay i never thought of using a try - catch, thanks for the answer :)